# Как показать людям результат промиса(не через console.log)?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, асинхронность, promise

есть три файла, exportUsers.js (импортирует данные из AD), есть app.js (конфиг datatables для форматирования таблицы и подключение данных которые используются при верстки таблицы) и собственно index.html. Вопрос у меня избитый скорее всего, как импортировать из промиса полученные в виде объекта данные (result(objUsers)) в файл app.js в data: **dataUsers**. Если брать данные из файла data.js (там массив объектов), в том формате который получает промис, все отлично загружается. Очень прошу помочь

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My Table</h1>
      <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-sm" style="width: 100%">
        <thead class="table-info"></thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js - сейчас данные берутся из файла, но надо что бы из промиса

```
import { dataArr, dataObj, dataUsers } from './_data/data.js'

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: dataUsers,
    columns: [
      { data: 'cn', title: 'ФИО' },
      { data: 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', title: 'Офис' },
      { data: 'streetAddress', title: 'Адрес' },
      { data: 'company', title: 'Организация' },
      { data: 'department', title: 'Место работы' },
      { data: 'title', title: 'Должность' },
      { data: 'telephoneNumber', title: 'Номер телефона' },
      { data: 'mail', title: 'Элетронный адрес' },
      { data: 'ipPhone', title: 'ipPhone' }],
    stateSave: true, //default - false
    lengthMenu: [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, 'All'],
    ],
    language: {
      url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.6/i18n/ru.json',
      searchPlaceholder: 'Строка поиска',
      zeroRecords: 'Записи для отображения отсутствуют',
    },
    pageLength: 25,
    pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  })
})
```

importUsersAD.js

```
import ActiveDirectory from 'activedirectory2'
import fs from 'fs'
import util from 'util'

const config = {
  url: 'ldap://server:389',
  baseDN: 'dc=domain,dc=ru',
  // Обычный Domain User, без изысков
  bindDN: 'user@domain.ru',
  password: 'hG5$bV......!fDzx1Kk#9Nm',
  attributes: {
    user: [
      'cn',
      'company',
      'physicalDeliveryOfficeName',
      'streetAddress',
      'department',
      'title',
      'ipPhone',
      'telephoneNumber',
      'mail',
      // 'thumbnailPhoto'
    ],
  },
}

const ad = new ActiveDirectory(config)
const query = '(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person))(!(objectClass=computer))(!(objectClass=group))(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(ipPhone=*)(title=*))'

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('Start request...')
  ad.findUsers(query, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      resolve('We have error: ' + JSON.stringify(err.message))
      return
    }
    
    resolve(JSON.stringify(users))
  })
})

myPromise
  .then((data) => {
    // console.log(typeof data, data)
    const objUsers = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log('Тип данных:', typeof objUsers, '\nКоличество объектов:', Object.keys(objUsers).length)
    console.dir(objUsers, { maxArrayLength: null })
    return objUsers


    // fs.writeFileSync('./temp.js', 'let obj = ' + util.inspect(array), 'utf-8')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log('End request!')
  })
```